# unable to show insert field for date type in javascript and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have a data grid page that allows inserting new records.  In the grid, one column is of date type. this column alone does not enable any data entry field. rest of the columns are okay as can be seen from the screenshot below. The yellow highlighted date field is displayed only and shows date and I can not insert any data entry here.

[image: image that shows the issue]

Now here is the HTML portion. I expect INS_DTPICKER_DATE input field to be a blank data entry field and it's not.

```
<!-- Effective Date -->
        <!-- Effective Date -->
<td>
   <span id="disp_eff_date"><?php echo date("m/d/Y",strtotime($row_wbs['EFFECTIVE_DATE'])); ?></span>
   <div class="form-group" style="display: none;" id="edit_eff_date_<?php echo $row_wbs['WBS_ID']; ?>">
      <input type = "text" class="form-control small form_datetime" required id="DTPicker_Date<?php echo $row_wbs['WBS_ID']; ?>" name="DTPicker_Date<?php echo $row_wbs['WBS_ID']; ?>" value ="<?php echo date("m/d/Y",strtotime($StartDate)); ?>" style="display: none; width:auto;">
      <input type = "text" class="form-control requirefieldcls small form_datetime"  required id="ins_DTPicker_Date" name="ins_DTPicker_Date" value ="">
      <span class="inp-icons"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
   </div>
</td>
```

Here is the Javascript code.

```
$("#cmdActivate").click(function() {    

   for(i=1;i<=20;i++)
   {

         $("#disp_SEGMENT_"+i).css("display", "none");
         $("#ins_SEGMENT"+i).css("display", "block");

   }
         $("#edit_eff_date_h).css("display", "block");
         $("#ins_DTPicker_Date").css("display", "block");
         $("#DTPicker_Date").css("display", "block");

         $("#ACTIVE_FLAG"+i).attr("disabled",false);
         $("#ACTIVE_FLAG"+i).attr("checked",false);
```

Comment: I'm confused what the issue is, so you want a date picker but instead you're just getting the date?

Comment: Hi Carson,  the issue is that the column "Date" ends up being a display only field even though,  there is explicit input tag "ins_DTPicker_date" is defined and updated through javascript.   Take a look at the nearby column  SubTask18.  It is an input field where I can enter a value.  I need to have date field do the same when a cursor is positioned into a date field, Once that happens, then a date calendar will be displayed allowing to input a date value in this field.   This is not happening only for the date column. other columns in  datagrid work fine as regard to accepting the input value.